# $md dialog quando carrega a página

Tags: angularjs

Preciso abrir o modal $md dialog quando carrego página, alguma sugestão?

```
$scope.showAdvanced = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'dialog1.tmpl.html',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `$timeout`:

```
$timeout($scope.showAdvanced, 0);
```

Não esqueça de injetar a dependência do `$timeout` para que funcione corretamente.

Comment: @SamuelSouza Isso aí

Answer (score 0):

Consegui aqui também dessa forma:

```
 $mdDialog.show({
    controller: DialogController,
    templateUrl: 'modalDialog.html',  
    scope: $scope,
  });
```